# How to show current date highlight in calender in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have problem in highlight the current day in my calender, I have attached my code with this.

```
<script language="javascript">
    <!--
    // fill the month table with column headings
    function day_title(day_name){
    document.write("<TD ALIGN=center WIDTH=35>"+day_name+"</TD>")
    }
    // fills the month table with numbers
    function fill_table(month,month_length)
    { 
    day=1
    // begin the new month table
    document.write("<TABLE BORDER=3 CELLSPACING=3 CELLPADDING=%3><TR>")
    document.write("<TD COLSPAN=7 ALIGN=center><B>"+month+"   "+year+"</B><TR>")
    // column headings
    day_title("Sun")
    day_title("Mon")
    day_title("Tue")
    day_title("Wed")
    day_title("Thu")
    day_title("Fri")
    day_title("Sat")
    // pad cells before first day of month
    document.write("</TR><TR>")
    for (var i=1;i<start_day;i++){
    document.write("<TD>")
    }
    // fill the first week of days
    for (var i=start_day;i<8;i++){
    document.write("<TD ALIGN=center>"+day+"</TD>")
    day++
    }
    document.write("<TR>")
    // fill the remaining weeks
    while (day <= month_length) {
    for (var i=1;i<=7 && day<=month_length;i++){
    document.write("<TD ALIGN=center>"+day+"</TD>")
    day++
    }
    document.write("</TR><TR>")
    // the first day of the next month
    start_day=i
    }
    document.write("</TR></TABLE><BR>")
    }
    // end hiding -->

    </script>

    <script language="javascript">

    // CAHNGE the below variable to the CURRENT YEAR
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getFullYear();

    year=n

    var leap = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0);
    var add = 0;
    if(leap == true ){
    add = 1;
    }
    //alert(add);


    // first day of the week of the new year
    today= new Date("January 1, "+year)
    start_day = today.getDay() + 1   // starts with 0
    fill_table("January",31)
    fill_table("February",28+add)
    fill_table("March",31)
    fill_table("April",30)
    fill_table("May",31)
    fill_table("June",30)
    fill_table("July",31)
    fill_table("August",31)
    fill_table("September",30)
    fill_table("October",31)
    fill_table("November",30)
    fill_table("December",31)
    </script>
```

In this calender, i want to highlight the current date, how to show ? 
Thanks

Answer (score -3):

You can use the datepicker function. [Refer this](http://runnable.com/UdTuotHbZoQNAABq/adding-a-date-picker-to-an-input-form-field-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to use date picker....I want to done this functionality with this code please edit from this code